# Setting unknown property: finance\entities\User\User::email_confirm_token

Tags: yii2

Приветствую,помогите плиииииз, ошибка при регистрации:

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Setting unknown property: finance\entities\User\User::email_confirm_token



1. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php at line 209

200                  $behavior->$name = $value;
201                return;
202            }
203        }
204 
205        if (method_exists($this, 'get' . $name)) {
206            throw new InvalidCallException('Setting read-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
207        }
208 
209        throw new UnknownPropertyException('Setting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
210    }
211 
212    /**
213     * Checks if a property is set, i.e. defined and not null.
214     *
215     * This method will check in the following order and act accordingly:
216     *
217     *  - a property defined by a setter: return whether the property is set
218     *  - a property of a behavior: return whether the property is set


2. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\BaseActiveRecord.php at line 321 – yii\base\Component::__set('email_confirm_token', 'hKAL0BCUdVDkr8Nl2w4Y4e9yEQesdPcr')
3. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\finance\entities\User\User.php at line 42 – yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::__set('email_confirm_token', 'hKAL0BCUdVDkr8Nl2w4Y4e9yEQesdPcr')


36                            $user = new User();
37        $user->username = $username;
38        $user->email = $email;
39        $user->setPassword($password);
40        $user->created_at = time();
41        $user->status = self::STATUS_WAIT;
42        $user->email_confirm_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
43        $user->generateAuthKey();
44        return $user;
45    }
46 
47    public function confirmSignup(): void
48    {


4. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\finance\services\auth\SignupService.php at line 21 – finance\entities\User\User::requestSignup('sveta', 'ddd@mail.ru', '60592swallow')

15                        }
16    public function signup(SignupForm $form): void
17    {
18        $user = User::requestSignup(
19            $form->username,
20            $form->email,
21            $form->password
22        );
23 
24        $this->save($user);
25 
26        $sent = $this->mailer
27            ->compose(


5. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\frontend\controllers\auth\SignupController.php at line 45 – finance\services\auth\SignupService::signup(finance\forms\auth\SignupForm)


39                         */
40    public function actionRequest()
41    {
42        $form = new SignupForm();
43        if ($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $form->validate()) {
44            try {
45                $this->service->signup($form);
46                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');
47                return $this->goHome();
48            } catch (\DomainException $e) {
49                Yii::$app->errorHandler->logException($e);
50                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
51            }


6. frontend\controllers\auth\SignupController::actionRequest()
7. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php at line 57 – call_user_func_array([frontend\controllers\auth\SignupController, 'actionRequest'], [])
8. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php at line 157 – yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams([])
9. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php at line 528 – yii\base\Controller::runAction('request', [])
10. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php at line 103 – yii\base\Module::runAction('auth/signup/request', [])
11. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php at line 386 – yii\web\Application::handleRequest(yii\web\Request)
12. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\frontend\web\index.php at line 17 – yii\base\Application::run()


11                        require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php',
12    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php',
13    require __DIR__ . '/../config/main.php',
14    require __DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php'
15);
16 
17(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Вот код пользователя User.php:

```
public static function requestSignup(string $username, string $email, string $password): self
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $username;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->setPassword($password);
        $user->created_at = time();
        $user->status = self::STATUS_WAIT;
        $user->email_confirm_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        return $user;
    }

    public function confirmSignup(): void
    {
        if (!$this->isWait()) {
            throw new \DomainException('User is already active.');
        }
        $this->status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
        $this->email_confirm_token = null;
    }

    public static function signupByNetwork($network, $identity): self
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->created_at = time();
        $user->status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->networks = [Network::create($network, $identity)];
        return $user;
    }
```

Вот код UserReposytory.php:

```
    public function getByEmailConfirmToken($token): User
    {
        return $this->getBy(['email_confirm_token' => $token]);
    }
    public function  getByEmail($email): User
    {
        return $this->getBy(['email' => $email]);
    }
```

Вот код SignupService.php:

```
public function confirm ($token): void
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            throw new \DomainException('Empty confirm token.');
        }

        $user = $this->getByEmailConfirmToken($token);
        $user->confirmSignup();
        $this->save($user);
    }

    private function getByEmailConfirmToken(string $token): User
    {
        if (!$user = User::findOne(['email_confirm_token' => $token])) {
            throw new \DomainException('User is not found.');
        }
        return $user;
    }
    private function save(User $user): void
    {
        if (!$user->save()) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Saving error.');
        }
    }
```

Вот код SignupController.php:

```
public function actionRequest()
    {
        $form = new SignupForm();
        if ($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $form->validate()) {
            try {
                $this->service->signup($form);
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');
                return $this->goHome();
            } catch (\DomainException $e) {
                Yii::$app->errorHandler->logException($e);
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return $this->render('request', [
            'model' => $form,
        ]);
     }

    /**
     * @param $token
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionConfirm($token)
    {
        try {
            $this->service->confirm($token);
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Your email is confirmed.');
            return $this->redirect(['auth/auth/login']);
        } catch (\DomainException $e) {
            Yii::$app->errorHandler->logException($e);
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this->goHome();
    }
```

Comment: Доброй ночи. Почему Вы не указали в каком файле, на какой строке происходит ошибка? Как понять? Выделите эту строку в коде.

Comment: @slo_nik Доброе утро вроде исправила.. И в интернете про неё ничего нет..((

Comment: Про что нет в инете?

Comment: По моей проблеме..

Comment: Ну как нет, есть конечно. По запросу "Setting unknown property" Вы найдёте кучу ответов, что это значит и как решить проблему.

Comment: Ищу, уже множество ответов испробовала.. Ошибка не исчезает